# How to investigate dhammas

Tags: vicaya

I've read a fair bit about the 7 factors of awakening but I'm really struggling with how I actually cultivate them. In particular dhamma vicaya or investigation of dhammas.  Can somebody give me a practical real world example of this? Nothing I have read is really sinking in. I need it explained to me like a 5 year old. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Dhammas can be investigated by understanding impermanence of Dhamma(except Nibbana).
Whichever Dhamma you think is the cause of your perplexity or cause of concern, you must recognise it as it is. For example- A joyous feeling is understood as joyful and painful feeling is understood as painful feeling. When you grasp the feeling , you must realise that it is impermanent. It will not last forever. It will not remain same forever. Therefore that feeling is not worth calling as me , mine or myself. And that which is not you, yours or yourself, should be discarded and you should remain calm, collected and blameless.

Answer (score 0):

Dhamma vicaya is investigating whether or not something brings harm & suffering.

[SN 46.2](https://suttacentral.net/sn46.2/en/bodhi?lang=en&reference=none&highlight=false) explains this:

> There are, bhikkhus, wholesome and unwholesome states, blameable and
> blameless states, inferior and superior states, dark and bright states
> with their counterparts: **frequently giving careful attention to** them
> is the nutriment for the arising of the unarisen enlightenment factor
> of discrimination of states and for the fulfilment by development of
> the arisen enlightenment factor of discrimination of states.

The above method is described in many suttas, such as:

> What do you think, Rāhula? What is the purpose of a mirror?” “It’s for
> checking your reflection, sir.” “In the same way, deeds of body,
> speech, and mind should be done only after **repeated checking**. ‘Does
> this act with the body that I want to do lead to hurting myself,
> hurting others, or hurting both? Is it unskillful, with suffering as
> its outcome and result?’ If, while checking in this way, you know:
> ‘This act with the body that I want to do leads to hurting myself,
> hurting others, or hurting both. It’s unskillful, with suffering as
> its outcome and result.’ To the best of your ability, Rāhula, you
> should not do such a deed. But if, while checking in this way, you
> know: ‘This act with the body that I want to do doesn’t lead to
> hurting myself, hurting others, or hurting both. It’s skillful, with
> happiness as its outcome and result.’ Then, Rāhula, you should do such
> a deed.
>
> [MN 61](https://suttacentral.net/mn61/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=plain&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)

> When you know for yourselves that, 'These qualities are unskillful;
> these qualities are blameworthy; these qualities are criticized by the
> wise; these qualities, when adopted & carried out, lead to harm & to
> suffering' — then you should abandon them.
>
> "What do you think, Kalamas? When greed arises in a person, does it
> arise for welfare or for harm?"
>
> "For harm, lord."
>
> "And this greedy person, overcome by greed, his mind possessed by
> greed, kills living beings, takes what is not given, goes after
> another person's wife, tells lies, and induces others to do likewise,
> all of which is for long-term harm & suffering."
>
> "Yes, lord."
>
> "Now, what do you think, Kalamas? When aversion arises in a person,
> does it arise for welfare or for harm?"
>
> "For harm, lord."
>
> "And this aversive person, overcome by aversion, his mind possessed by
> aversion, kills living beings, takes what is not given, goes after
> another person's wife, tells lies, and induces others to do likewise,
> all of which is for long-term harm & suffering."
>
> "Yes, lord."
>
> "Now, what do you think, Kalamas? When delusion arises in a person,
> does it arise for welfare or for harm?"
>
> "For harm, lord."
>
> "And this deluded person, overcome by delusion, his mind possessed by
> delusion, kills living beings, takes what is not given, goes after
> another person's wife, tells lies, and induces others to do likewise,
> all of which is for long-term harm & suffering."
>
> "Yes, lord."
>
> "So what do you think, Kalamas: Are these qualities skillful or
> unskillful?"
>
> "Unskillful, lord."
>
> "Blameworthy or blameless?"
>
> "Blameworthy, lord."
>
> "Criticized by the wise or praised by the wise?"
>
> "Criticized by the wise, lord."
>
> "When adopted & carried out, do they lead to harm & to suffering, or
> not?"
>
> "When adopted & carried out, they lead to harm & to suffering. That is
> how it appears to us."
>
> [AN 3.65](https://accesstoinsight.org/ati/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.065.than.html)

Comment: Thanks but I just gloss over when people quote scripture as an answer

Comment: Dhamma vicaya is investigating whether or not something brings harm & suffering. That's it.

Comment: The scripture says: "There are wholesome and unwholesome states, blameable and blameless states". Dhamma vicaya is investigating what is wholesome; what is unwholesome; what brings peace & happiness; what brings harm & suffering. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Buddhist investigation (2nd factor of enlightenment) happens automatically when you develop the 1st factor of mindfulness as described in Satipaṭṭhānasutta ([MN10](https://suttacentral.net/mn10/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=sidebyside&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=false&script=latin)).  All phenomena can be digested with reference to the four frames - body, feeling, mind, principles.

According to Satipaṭṭhānasutta mindfulness results in the following:

> “This is the direct path for the purification of beings, for the
> overcoming of sorrow & lamentation, for the disappearance of pain &
> distress, for the attainment of the right method, & for the
> realization of unbinding—in other words, the four establishings of
> mindfulness.

My guess is *right method* means mindfulness is the right method of investigation.